# How to handle self join in EntityDataSource?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I wonder how to handle self join in EntityDataSource .

IF I have i query like this :

```
SELECT b.degree_name ,c.degree_name as degree_next
FROM EMPDEGPROM a INNER JOIN  DEGREEWORK b
ON a.degree_code=b.degree_code
INNER JOIN DEGREEWORK c
ON a.next_degree_code =c.degree_code
WHERE a.emp_num=6777
```

---

How to use this data source as EntityDataSource.?

I try to do this but i can't get `degree_next`

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EmpPromotionsDS" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="name=CTX" DefaultContainerName="CTX" EnableFlattening="False"
            EntitySetName="EMPDEGPROMs" EntityTypeFilter="EMPDEGPROM" Where="it.EMP_NUM =@emp_num"  Include="DEGREEWORK" >
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="emp_num" SessionField="emp_num" DbType="Int32" />
            </WhereParameters>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view.

```
CREATE VIEW XXX AS
SELECT a.emp_num, b.degree_name ,c.degree_name as degree_next
FROM EMPDEGPROM a INNER JOIN  DEGREEWORK b
ON a.degree_code=b.degree_code
INNER JOIN DEGREEWORK c
ON a.next_degree_code =c.degree_code
```

EF has no problem reading from views.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,just after i create the view as you said ,i have to add primary key to use that view `alter view XXX add constraint vemp_pk primary key (emp_num,degree_code) disable1`

Answer (score 1):

- If you want only readonly, you could drop the EntitySetName, EntityTypeFilter, Where and Include properties and use instead use the [CommandText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.commandtext(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
- If you want to use directly your entities, make sure you have a navigation property with a self reference and precise it in your include property.

```html
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EmpPromotionsDS" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="name=CTX" 
            DefaultContainerName="CTX" 
            EnableFlattening="False"
            CommandText= SELECT b.degree_name ,c.degree_name as degree_next
                         FROM EMPDEGPROM a INNER JOIN  DEGREEWORK b
                         ON a.degree_code=b.degree_code
                         INNER JOIN DEGREEWORK c
                         ON a.next_degree_code =c.degree_code
                         WHERE a.emp_num=@EmployeeId>
<CommandParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="EmployeeId" ControlID="EmployeeIdTextBox" Type="Int32"/>
</CommandParameters>
```

Comment: kindly , Could you change the Entity datasource in your answer so that i could get what you mean

Comment: I want to use LINQ not TSQL , the developer should have no idea about DB structure .